# How to write Groovy script in Jenkins to read the value in given html file from project directory

Tags: html, jenkins, groovy, protractor

I have problems on config jenkins job, i need to use a groovy script in jenkins to read / get the `passed` value in given html file, then i can use this value in my jenkins notification email.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cucumber Feature Report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <a class="navbar-brand">Cucumberjs Report</a>
          <div class="project-name visible-md visible-lg">protractor-cucumber-tests</div>
          <div class="label-container">
            <span class="label label-success" title=scenarios>Passed: 5</span>
            <span class="label label-danger" title=scenarios>Failed: 25</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyone can help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Much appreciate if anyone can help